# D3 dinut chart displaying more decimals than required

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KRhjrOTJEXgqmu4Ok0eM?p=preview) where i am using angularjs and d3.js.

I am generating a few donut charts here i would like to know how to display the average of the data in the middle of the arc.

My function works well and displays the calculations. But i want the number of decimals to be restricted to just 2. How do i do it?

```
svg.append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("class", "inside")
        .text(function(d) { 
            return (data[0]*4+data[1]*3+data[2]*2+data[3])/d3.sum(data);  
        });
```

Comment: `.toFixed(2)` to the rescue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/q8pdzsQF3EAgzRLOJDNZ?p=preview).

[`d3.format()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting) is the idiomatic way to do this with d3 :

```
var format = d3.format('.2f');// 2 decimal places
...
...
.text(function(d) { 
  return format( (data[0]*4+data[1]*3+data[2]*2+data[3])/d3.sum(data) );  
});
```